# How to get SSL using Let's Encrypt! when my hostname is hosted by wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I have a site www.testsite.com that is hosted by wordpress.com, I'm trying to issue a certificate so I can have https.

Is there any good methods to use when I cannot really install letsEncrypt's ACME client on my wordpress.com's account?

Comment: Let's Encrypt can do DNS-based auth, I think, but what good is this going to do you? WordPress won't let you upload the resulting SSL certificate to their servers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to issue your certificate for your wordpress (and actually, for any other website type), is to [install (clone) Let's encrypt](https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt) to your machine.

The main and very basic idea is that Let's Encrypt (LE) wants you to prove that you do have access control to your domain. This is achieved through a challenge. You have to output a string they provide you inside a folder. For example, at yourwordpress.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/
the (LE) authority wants to read a long string it provides you.

So, inside your wordpress site folder, create those directories.

Once this is successfully checked, LE, saves your ssl certificates in your local machine with root privileges.

Now you have to upload those certificates *.pem to your server. This last step is different depending on the company server.

[Here is a nice tutorial](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/tutorial-for-os-x-local-certificates-and-shared-hosting/6859?source_topic_id=8407) that worked for me to get the LE certificates.